# Random product collection, getPriceHTML gives wrong values

Tags: price, ce-1.8.0.0, product-collection

I am creating a random list of products that refreshes every hour. I've got most of it done but there is one problem: `getPriceHTML` is returning `NULL`. This function is used in the normal category product lists and works perfectly there.

This code does give a correct `getPriceHTML`

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

But what I need is to get a random product, no matter what category it is in, so that is not an option.

The following code is the code I use to get random products:

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($this->_productCollection);
$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$this->_productCollection->addStoreFilter();
$this->_productCollection->setPage(1, 3);
```

And later on:

```
foreach($this->_productCollection AS $_product)
{
    echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
}
```

For simple products this does give the correct price, but it returns `NULL` for grouped products. Yes, I am extending to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product`.

Please keep in mind that I know that there are other functions to get the price, but I specifically want to know why this isn't working as it should.

Comment: The default method looks like this     "public function getPriceHtml($product)" Do you have customised the getPriceHtml method that requires the additional true param?

Comment: I will check it out, If so, I have not done it myself. This is the code that has been used in the list.phtml

Comment: @Fooman I am not seeing why they added the `true` at that function, since it doesn't seem to be overridden in any way. Removing it still gives the same result too anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the two implementations for getPriceHtml()

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
{
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
    $this->setProduct($product);
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

vs.

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract

```
public function getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice = false, $idSuffix = '')
{
    return $this->_preparePriceRenderer($product->getTypeId())
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
        ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
        ->toHtml();
}
```

extending from the Abstract block should help in getting the correct renderer.

Comment: As a sidenote Mage_Catalog_Block_Product does not extend from the Abstract block, sigh...

Comment: So that is where the `true` came from, that explains a lot! Extending to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` did fix it for me, thanks!